# paypal checkouts for marketplace

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I would really like to use Paypal for my marketplace I am developing. I need to allow users to enter their paypal email address and whenever customers purchase that users products I take a small fee then the rest of the money goes to the user who listed the product.

What paypal service is the best for these types of payments? (me taking a transaction fee and sending the rest of the money to another paypal account)

I was looking into paypal express checkout, but can't find any info on sending some payouts to the users listing products. Also does express checkout require that the customer have a paypal account?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are wondering and finding an answer, Express Checkout now comes with Parallel Payments. Read it [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/). As Adaptive Payment Parallel Payment now deprecated, the option left is using Express Checkout.

Comment: Isn't it not recommended to use the deprecated API? Also it seems adaptive payments is invite only... I'm thinking I'm just going to use stripe

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to get a sensible answer from PayPal for days now. They are planning to release a protocol to support a market place in 2020 but not date yet. They have also confirmed (after talking to sales & tech support) that PayPal cannot be used for market places where your platform is nothing more than a broker.

Stripe Connect (Standard account) is probably the best solution out there.